# Try Catch statement is breaking my code

Tags: .net, powershell, try-catch

This is a little piece of Powershell script, to get all folders/subfolders and files recursively, i can't use `Get-ChildItem` because it's too much slow on UNC network path, so my idea is to use `[Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem]::GetFiles` executed remotely using PSSession, and it works.

With this code executed remotely with PsSession, my try/catch statement is working perfectly, i can get the result into `$GetRemoteFolderCheck` variable.

```
$path_folder = "C:\sources\sql"

    $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ipsqlserver -Credential $credentials
        Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
        [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("Microsoft.VisualBasic") | Out-Null
        }

        $GetRemoteFolderCheck = Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
           try
           {
            [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem]::GetFiles(
            $using:path_folder,
            [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption]::SearchAllSubDirectories)
           }
           catch
           {
               return $_
           }
        }
```

**But when i execute the same code locally** without using PSSession, it's not working, it's breaking my code... because the `Write-Host` is not displayed in my shell

```
$path_folder = "C:\sources\sql"

$GetLocalFolderCheck =  try{[Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem]::GetFiles(
        $path_folder,
        [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption]::SearchAllSubDirectories) }
        catch
        {
           return $_
        }

    Write-Host "toto"
```

I don't understand why it's not working as expected, my `$GetlocalFolderCheck` should contains the exception, and not breaking my code.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `return` statement this is expected behaviour. `Write-Host "toto"` is effectively unreachable as you are returning a value no matter whether your call succeeds or throws an error. Were this C# code, there would be compilation warning `Unreachable code detected`.

You should be able to achieve the desired result by changing the catch block to:

```
...
catch
       {
           $_
       }
...
```

This way if there is an error, it will be passed up the pipeline as an object and execution will carry on.

Comment: Thank you very much. Beginner mistake :)